# Data is not inserting to database table

Tags: iphone, database, web-services, sqlite

I stored images in server url and fetching that images from JSON then writing to local database. But NSLog displaying `categories insert is insert into categories (id,cat_name,order_by) values('3','test','3')`. But values are not showing in db1.sqlite file.

code:

File Manager:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *err;

    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db4" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"bundlePath %@", bundlePath);


  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", documentsDirectory);

    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];

  BOOL success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];


    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Fetching data from server url add to  database file:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverurl.net/projects/mobile/jsonstring.php"];

     NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];



    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);



    NSArray *userData = [stringFromFileAtURL JSONValue];
    [stringFromFileAtURL release];


    NSLog(@"userdata is %@", userData);

    int  i = 0;
    BOOL notExist = TRUE;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;


    for (NSArray *skarray in userData) {
        //NSLog(@"test");


        if(i == 0){
            //insert all main category
            for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {

              if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

                    const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM categories where id = '%@'",[tuser objectForKey:@"id"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    NSLog(@"categories select is %s", sql);

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                        notExist = TRUE;

                        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                            notExist = FALSE;

                        }

                    }



                    if(notExist){


                        NSLog(@"categories does not exist");


                     //   const char *sqlInsert = "insert into categories (id,cat_name,order_by) Values(?, ?, ?)";

                        const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into categories (id,cat_name,order_by) values('%@','%@','%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"id"], [tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"],[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                        NSLog(@"categories insert is %s", sqlInsert);

                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



                        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 0, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))

   NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                        else
                            sqlite3_reset(addStmt);

      }

                    sqlite3_close(database);


                }



            }
        }
```

I asked so many questions. But didn't get solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database insert failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348931/database-insert-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter indexes are wrong; they must start at 1, and your statement does not have any parameters.

You don't need `sqlite3_reset`.

You must always call [sqlite3_finalize](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).

Comment: After removing else sqlite3_reset(addStmt); this line, not working

Comment: My answer also has a second sentence.

Comment: I inserted sqlite3_finalize. But still it's not working. I don't know where is the error? Can you check? I stuck with last 4days