# Database insert failed

Tags: iphone, database, json, sqlite

I stored details in my server. Im using server url for fetching detail and store to database table. I got insertion failed NSLog. I have 2 sqlite file in documents folder. After copyItemAtPath, im writing to that file.

code:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSError *err;

     NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db5" ofType:@"sqlite"];
     //NSLog(@"bundlePath %@", bundlePath);


     //call update function to check any data updated,
     //if there is a version difference
     //update the data base with all the required fileds.



     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     //NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", documentsDirectory);

     NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];

     //  [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];

     BOOL success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];


     if (!success) {
     NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [err localizedDescription]);
     }



    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.net/projects/mobile/jsonstring.php"];



    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"response is %@", stringFromFileAtURL);

      NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);



    //array

    NSArray *userData = [stringFromFileAtURL JSONValue];
    [stringFromFileAtURL release];


   // NSLog(@"userdata is %@", userData);

    int  i = 0;
     BOOL notExist = TRUE;
 //   sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;


    for (NSArray *skarray in userData) {
        //NSLog(@"test");


        if(i == 0){
            //insert all main category
            for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {


NSString *query = @"delete from categories";
                    const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
                    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
                    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                            // Read the data from the result row
                            NSLog(@"result is here");
                        }

                        // Release the compiled statement from memory
                        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


                    }

               if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


                    NSLog(@"path is %s", [path UTF8String]);


                    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = NULL;
                    const char *sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO categories (id,cat_name,order_by) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

                    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL);
                    if(result != SQLITE_OK){
                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    }

                    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 0, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                    //Execute the statement
                    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
                        result = sqlite3_step(addStmt);
                    }

                    if (result == SQLITE_DONE || result == SQLITE_ROW) {
                        result = sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
                        NSLog(@"Inserted");
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"InsertFailed");
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. If you want to know why the insert failed, replace

   ```
   NSLog(@"InsertFailed");
   ```

   With

   ```
   NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   ```

   Whenever you get a SQL error, examine what the error is, or else you're flying blind.
2. The SQLite `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions use a 1-based index (unlike the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions). So replace:

   ```
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 0, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   ```

   with:

   ```
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   ```

   or, even better:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"bind of 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"bind of 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"bind of 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   ```

   or, even better:

   ```
   if ([[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   else
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_null(addStmt, 1) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of null to 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }

   if ([[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   else
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_null(addStmt, 2) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of null to 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }

   if ([[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   else
   {
       if (sqlite3_bind_null(addStmt, 3) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSLog(@"bind of null to 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   ```
3. Replace your `sqlite3_reset` with `sqlite3_finalize`. `sqlite3_reset` resets the statement so you can bind new values and execute it again (which is not what you need here). `sqlite3_finalize` frees the memory associated with the prepared statement (which *is* what you need).
4. By the way, your code copies the file from the bundle to Documents regardless if the database was already there or not (meaning you'll discard anything you inserted the next time your run the app). You presumably want to replace:

   ```
    BOOL success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
   ```

   with

   ```
   if (![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:appFile]) {
       BOOL success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:appFile error:&err];

       if (!success) {
           NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [err localizedDescription]);
       }
   }
   ```
5. All of the above fix the simple logic errors in your code sample. You still have the deeper problem that your JSON (which I assume is unchanged from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265500/image-is-not-fetching-from-database)) will not conform to this nested `for` loop structure you've got here. Your three arrays are different types of arrays. Or have you changed your JSON format since that other question?

Comment: After changing 1-based index, i got inserted log. But data is not inserting to db1.sqlite table. I opened db1.sqlite file through SQLiteManager. But table doesn't have any values. Why?

Comment: @user2674668 Are you running this on the simulator? Are you opening the database in the simulator's Document's folder (as opposed to the copy in your project's folder or the app's bundle)? It's located in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ .... You might have to execute `chflags nohidden ~/Library` if you can't see your Library folder in Mac OS.

Comment: Im getting NSLog below: bind of 1 failed: bind or column index out of range, bind of 2 failed: bind or column index out of range, bind of 3 failed: bind or column index out of range

Comment: @user2674668 But no error on `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement? It would suggest that your SQL doesn't have the three `?` placeholders in it or that the prepare failed for some reason.

Comment: I used /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/9B3D0FE2-4AA2-41CC-B3B3-C9EEF90E5146/Documents/db1.sqlite. It's showing all the datas from this path. Thanks

Comment: After inserting when i use select *from categories from SQLiteManager, it displaying values multiple times(previously shown values)

Comment: @user2674668 Yeah, I would have expected that on the basis of your code sample. You're just inserting values on the basis of the JSON. But you're not bothering to check to see if the value was already there. If you had a primary key defined for your table, you could use the SQL syntax `INSERT OR REPLACE`. Otherwise, delete the value before you try inserting it again. (Or update if it exists, insert if it doesn't). Lots of ways to skin the cat here. Just don't simply  insert again and again, or else you'll see the behavior you're currently experiencing.

Comment: Can you check my edited code? NSString *query = @"delete from categories";  I used this line for delete

Comment: @user2674668 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35899/discussion-between-rob-and-user2674668)

Answer (score -1):

[Well check Out  here for detailed code structure.](http://myiostricks.blogspot.in/2013/07/another-great-day.html)

The way I manage is a seperate class to manage DB

and these are the methods you look for

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:nil];

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
#pragma mark - Helper methods
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

-(BOOL)dbOpenedSuccessfully
{
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dbPath] UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                   message:@"Error on opening the DB"
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        return NO;
    }
}






//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
#pragma mark - Query
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


- (void) executeQuery:(NSString *)strQuery
{
    char *error = NULL;
    if([self dbOpenedSuccessfully])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",strQuery);
        sqlite3_exec(_database, [strQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL,&error);
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"%s",error);
        }
        sqlite3_close(_database);
    }

}
```